# Rails Monologue Filter Tags Button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, monologue

Hi I am trying to create a button that filters monologue blog posts. I know that you can create links of tags that then filters the blog and just shows blog posts with the following tag.

This is my code is HAML:

```
    .btn-group 
    - = link_to "Tech", tag_url(@tags.first), class: "button btn btn-default green-btn btn-bordered black-text"
    .button.btn.btn-default.green-btn.btn-bordered.black-text Tech
    .button.btn.btn-default.green-btn.btn-bordered.black-text#news.active{:onclick => "activate()"} News
    .button.btn.btn-default.green-btn.btn-bordered.black-text Lifestyle
```

Right now I am just trying to link to the first tag in the tags list. However when I try to click on this I get this error in the browser:

"SyntaxError at /
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end"

and this snippet of code:

```
        unless source.valid_encoding?
      raise WrongEncodingError.new(@source, Encoding.default_internal)
    end
    begin
      mod.module_eval(source, identifier, 0)
      ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self, Finalizer[method_name, mod])
    rescue => e # errors from template code
      if logger = (view && view.logger)
        logger.debug "ERROR: compiling #{method_name} RAISED #{e}"
        logger.debug "Function body: #{source}"
```

This is the code that creates links out of the existing tags and filters by tag when clicked on: (this code works).

```
.row
.col-md-12.centered-text.tag-cloud
    - @tags.each do |tag|
        = link_to tag.name, tag_url(tag), class: label_for_tag(tag,@tags_frequency_min,@tags_frequency_max)
        &nbsp;
```

Anyone have any ideas? I have had a bit of a hard time finding monologue documentation

Comment: Please share the code for @tags in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The unique thing I can see is that

```
- = link_to "Tech", tag_url(@tags.first), class: "button btn btn-default green-btn btn-bordered black-text"
```

Remove the leading `-` and if the link hast to be inside the `.btn-group`, then add the proper indentation.

Comment: Thanks. I did that and I got this error in the browser: "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass". I think the - is needed for haml syntax to let it know it's ruby code

Comment: `=` is equal to `<%= ... %>` in erb notation and `-` is equal to `<% ... %>` Now your problem is that your @tags is probably an empty array

Comment: Oh thanks! I added a few tags using the rails console though so the tags array should not be empty